# How can I eliminate the space produced between list?

Tags: html, css, reveal.js

I am using reveal.js to create a presentation. I am creating a list, but an undesirable space appears. An example can be seen at the slide http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/#/20/1. You can see that between "shrink" and "fade-out" a space appears. I'd like to remove that space.

I'm using fragments. Is there any other option to get that idea? In [beamer](/questions/tagged/beamer) the command is `\only` to replace.

The original code is:

```
<section>
<h2>Fragment Styles</h2> 
<p>There's a few styles of fragments, like:</p>
<p class="fragment grow">grow</p>
<p class="fragment shrink">shrink</p>
<p class="fragment roll-in">roll-in</p>
<p class="fragment fade-out">fade-out</p>                    
<p class="fragment highlight-red">highlight-red</p>                                                 
<p class="fragment highlight-green">highlight-green</p>                     
<p class="fragment highlight-blue">highlight-blue</p>                                                 
<p class="fragment current-visible">current-visible</p>  
<p class="fragment highlight-current-blue">highlight-current-blue</p>
</section>
```

Then, when "roll-in" doesn't appear, "fade-out" should be use in that position, and when "roll-in" appears "fade-out" should move down.

Comment: Please post the relevant code to reproduce the problem here.

Comment: It's because the <p> tag for 'roll-out' has opacity: 0 and visibility: hidden. So it's not a space, it's just a word that has zero visibility.